# Asymmetric Hessian with Heavyside function?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I have a  function of the form
$$f(x,y) = \int_{0}^{\infty} H(x,y,z) \mu(z) dz$$
where
$$H(x,y,z) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } g(x,y) \geq z \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}  \end{cases}$$
for some strictly increasing continuously differentiable function $g$, and $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mu(z) dz= 1$.

Since the Dirac Delta function is the derivative of the Heavyside function, I have that
$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} = \delta(g(x,y)-z)$$

Exchanging integration and differentiation, this gives me
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \delta(g(x,y)-z)\mu(z)dz = \mu(g(x,y))$$

Now, if I take the derivative of this with respect to y, I get
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} =\mu'(g(x,y)) \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}.$$

If I first differentiated with respect to $y$, and then differentiated with respect to $x$, I would get
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} =\mu'(g(x,y)) \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}.$$

The two second-derivatives are *not* necessarily equal. Is this normal for distributional derivatives, or did I make a mistake somewhere?